# How to select range of dates from list on providing searching criteria

Tags: c#, linq

```
   DateInfo[] dateInfo= GetDateInfo();

   DateInfo[] searchDates  = null;
   DateTime dtfrom = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);
   DateTime dtTo = DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text);
   searchDates = dateInfo.Where(p => p.AddDate >= dtfrom || p.AddDate < dtTo).ToArray<DateInfo>();
```

if list contain

```
11/17/13,11/18/13,11/19/13,11/19/13,11/19/13,11/20/13,11/20/13
```

and I have entered

```
11/17/13 to 11/19/13
```

it should return

```
11/17/13,11/18/13,11/19/13,11/19/13,11/19/13
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
searchDates = dateInfo.Where(p => p.AddDate >= dtfrom && p.AddDate <= dtTo)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
searchDates = dateInfo
   .Where(p => p.AddDate >= dtfrom && p.AddDate <= dtTo)
   .ToArray<DateInfo>();
```

AND in this case will force to filter dates that are between, while your condition will cover everything.

Comment: its not working, just returning 11/17/13,11/19/13,11/19/13,11/19/13

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers.My problem resolved by writing this query

```
searchDates  = dateInfo.Where(p => (p.AddDate.Date.Year >= dtfrom.Date.Year && p.AddDate.Date.Month >= dtfrom.Date.Month && p.AddDate.Date.Day >= dtfrom.Date.Day) && (p.AddDate.Date.Year <= dtTo.Date.Year && p.AddDate.Date.Month <= dtTo.Date.Month && p.AddDate.Date.Day <= dtTo.Date.Day)).ToArray<DateInfo>();
```